# OCLint and xcode project

Tags: ios, xcode, oclint

since yesterday I'm trying to make OCLint works with my iOS project.

What I've done so far is to follow these [instructions](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/intro/installation.html) to install OCLint, then I've followed these [other instructions](http://docs.oclint.org/en/dev/guide/xcode.html) to use it within Xcode. The problem is that when I try to build the OCLint aggregate target the build process never end (I've waited 30 minutes before stopping it). Is someone experiencing the same issue? the OCLint version I'm using is [oclint-0.9.dev.3f9355e](http://archives.oclint.org/nightly/oclint-0.9.dev.3f9355e-x86_64-darwin-12.4.0.zip)

Answer (score 2):

try this on Terminal

```
xctool -workspace xx.xcworkspace -scheme xx -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json clean

xctool -workspace xx.xcworkspace -scheme xx -reporter json-compilation-database:compile_commands.json build

oclint-json-compilation-database
```